# Administrative boundaries of Brazil?

Tags: shapefile, data, coordinates, borders, brazil

I am looking for coordinates (longitude and latitude) of each state of Brazil.
Where can I find that?

I have found a file for the US states here: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/states.xml, I am now looking for something similar for Brazil.

Comment: I am looking for state boundaries. I have a list of cities defined by their coordinates (longitude and latitude). For each city, I want to find which state it belongs to. I need a format I can read with my python program, so xml or json would be a good choice. I don't know geojson

Comment: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to getting data about administrative boundaries of Brazil (and other types of public GIS data in the country), I advise looking first in the website of [Brazilian Institute of Geography and Statistics](http://www.ibge.gov.br/english/) (aka IBGE). The institute is responsible to make the survey and keep the data updated. Most of these data can be found in https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/ (folder and filenames are in Portuguese).

The information you want can be found here:

https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2020/Brasil/BR/. This is the link for 2020 data (previous years are available in parent directories).

Download the file named: `br_unidades_federacao.zip` (which means Brazil's states). The other files in that folder are mesoregion, microregion and county  administrative boundaries.

The CRS adopted in IBGE's shapefiles is [SIRGAS 2000](http://georepository.com/crs_4674/SIRGAS-2000.html) ([EPSG:4674](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/sirgas-2000/)).

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at the [Global Administrative Boundaries project](http://www.gadm.org/country). Several different formats to choose from, and you can select the level at which you'd like boundaries (for states, you might just need level 0).

When I ran through this workflow, I selected KMZ format and level 2, extracted the KML file via 7-zip, and used [this service](http://www.monster.com.tw/kml2csv) to get the coordinates in CSV. YMMV using this approach and especially that web service, but hopefully it gets you on your way.

Answer (score 1):

The OSM boundaries application **https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries** provides downloads of borders of administrative units that are mappen in OpenStreetMap. Maybe that will be of use to you.

Comment: I could download the brazil state boundaries on the OSM website. I think it's almost what I need. I have the coordinates of each boundary I guess, "geometry" : {
      "type" : "MultiPolygon",
      "coordinates" : [ [ [ [ -73.9830624, -7.5347343 ], [ -73.9830331, -7.5343613 ], [ -73.9816186, -7.5334893 ], [ -73.9803063, -7.5333091 ], however there is no correspondance with the states name :(

Comment: Url is outdated, page moved to https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/

Answer (score 1):

> I need a format I can read with my python program, so xml or json would be a good choice. I don't know geojson.

You can download any data format, such as a shapefile, of the borders. Then open that dataset in QGIS, and export it to GeoJSON (or download GeoJSON right away). Then right-click that .geojson file and open it in any text-editor, such as Notepad++. You will now see each vertex (i.e. coordinate) in that dataset (attention: the coordinates are in the coordinate system that you have used, so if you need to see lat/lon coordinates, make sure to save the dataset as WGS84 - EPSG:4326). If you do not have access to QGIS you can also use different online converters; there are a few out there.